# How to find area with double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have an area bounded by $0 \le x \le 3, 0 \le y \le 3, |x-y| \le 2$.

I plugged these 3 bounds to desmos and got the following bounded region. How do I use these three bounds to form a double integral?
[image]

Comment: You may not like this but it may honestly be cleanest to integrate over the whole square and then just subtract out those corners. It's going to have to be 3 integrals either way if you need to integrate over that region.

Comment: Why using a sledgehammer to break a nut ? The area is clearly $9-1=8$...

Comment: @JeanMarie I wasn't sure if he meant he needed to integrate something *over* that area, or alternatively if this was an integration exercise.

Comment: @JeanMarie if it is a double integral exercise then one has no choice but to use sledgehammer unless you can assure OP that their teacher will accept a geometry answer in a double integral  exercise.

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint_R f(x,y)\,dA = \int_0^1\int_0^{3-x} f(x,y)\,dy\,dx + \int_1^2\int_0^3 f(x,y)\,dy\,dx + \int_2^3\int_{x-2}^3f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$